# Divs in asp.net?

Tags: css

Using styles, want to place two divs in my web application side by side, like in stackoverflow left side portion is there na like that. i tried like

```
<div style="width:60%; " >

</div>

  <div style="width:40%; ">    

</div>
```

but the divs are coming next line to another div, i want the div come side by side with 60 and 40 % width. can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I am not keen on the use of floats to align things...you can do this...which splits the screen across two div elements ( a bit like frames )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Template</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body
            {
                /* height: 100%; removed as per user comments */ 
            }

            .div1
            {
                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
                display: inline-block;
                /* height: 100%; removed as per user comments */ 
                width: 60%;
                float: left;
            }

            .div2
            {
                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0000FF;
                display: inline-block;
                /* height: 100%; removed as per user comments */ 
                width: 40%;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div1">
            I am Div1 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div1 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div1 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div1 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div1 and this is my content<br/>
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
            I am Div2 and this is my content<br/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also note that it is not always wise to use inline styling. rather use css paths, classes or id's

Comment: i don't want to fix the height it should increase/decrease automatically when data is there or not, is it works Mr. Activwerx

Comment: @Suryasasidhar, in which case, just remove the height styles from the CSS (height: 100%;)

Comment: @Suryasasidhar I have not tested across multiple browsers, but in that respect, look into HTML 5 Boilerplate's CSS normalization...its a fantastic CSS file for creating multi-browser sites!   http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: thank you for your response, i have one doubt. can i ask here or can i create new question for that? regarding style only

Comment: @Suryasasidhar, ask away...if you feel it deserves a new question, that might be more beneficial...up to you!

Comment: ok, actually i developed a video site called www.videoozone.com, in that if the title of the video is too long then the design is disturbing can you look my site once so that you can under stand.

Answer (score 2):

Add `float:left` to both the divs and it should work

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JvBJT/